# A required class was missing while executing net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, apache-commons-lang3

Jenkins mvn --version:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /appl/xxx/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Locally mvn --version:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_332, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_332/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

So locally I can run everything just fine, I run my code on an offline jenkins server but its repository is exactly same as mine local (I've uploaded everything manually) so I really don't understand the problem.

I run my testcases using maven using following command on Jenkins (locally with mvn in front):

`-U clean install -PTestExecutor`

this is my `pom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

        <cucumber.version>7.3.3</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>4.2.1</selenium.version>
        <awaitility.version>4.2.0</awaitility.version>
        <assertj.version>3.23.1</assertj.version>
        <commonsmodel.version>5.3.3</commonsmodel.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M6</maven.surefire.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.8.2</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <maven-cucumber-reporting.version>5.7.0</maven-cucumber-reporting.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>TestExecutor</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <includes>**/ExecutorTest.java</includes>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!--cucumber report plugin-->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-cucumber-reports</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <projectName>Automation report</projectName>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</inputDirectory>
                                    <jsonFiles>
                                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                                    </jsonFiles>
                                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

and this is the error stack trace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate (generate-cucumber-reports) on project testing: Execution generate-cucumber-reports of goal net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0:generate: org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/net/masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting/5.7.0/maven-cucumber-reporting-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/appl/xxx/maven/repo/net/masterthought/cucumber-reporting/5.7.0/cucumber-reporting-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/appl/xxxf/maven/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[JENKINS] Archiving /appl/xxx/jenkins/workspace/Customer_Portal/web-full-suite/pom.xml to com.xxx/testing/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testing-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /appl/xxx/jenkins/workspace/Customer_Portal/web-full-suite/target/testing-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.xxx/testing/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testing-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

but as far as I can tell my `commons-lang3` dependency is set, its jar is added to the Artifactory. I tried multiple versions but at no hail.

Thanks

Comment: Which. Maven are you running? Can you check via `mvn --version` on plain command line and post the result here in your question..

Comment: true, thanks. added! I now see a difference locally <--> jenkins server: on the Jenkins it's ```3.3.9``` whereas locally I run ```3.8.3``` . Is it just an upgrade I can ask on the devops?

Comment: Actually there are some other differences as well: this is my local --version
```Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_332, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: /Users/market1/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_332/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```